# get method info into attribute in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, methodinfo

I want to get method info into attribute in C#.

something like this

**Attribute**

```
public class ReflectionAttribute : Attribute
    {
      public ReflectionAttribute()
      {      
                //reflection things comes here 

                // for example
                // var myMethod =  this.GetMethodInfo()
                // or something ... 

      }

    }
```

**Class**

```
 public  class ReflectionTest
    {

      [Reflection()]
      public string SendMessage()
      {

          return "Hello World";

      }

    }
```

**Test Class**

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new ReflectionTest().SendMessage();
        }
    }
```

I just want to get information about SendMessage method inside attribute when SendMessage method is invoked from Form1.

is it possible?  **Is there any way in reflection**

thank you.

Comment: Sure - how far have you got so far? Have you worked out how to get the relevant `MethodInfo`? Look for `GetCustomAttributes`...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Murat, make sure you check out this article, it provides tips on how to craft a even better question. [ask]

Comment: Maybe I thought to much into this question but I had the feeling that "inside attribute when ... invoked" sounded for me as a prolog/epilog thing.

Comment: Ok ,ok... I know my English is no good.... :)  

I changed my words...

thank you

Comment: // var myMethod =  this.GetMethodInfo()  

just example. I know there is not GetMethodInfo()  method. is there any way like reflection.

Comment: @MuratCabuk: Would you like to delete my answer as it is a misunderstanding? (well it could be my English too :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's not directly possible. 
In my case, I want to get MethodInfo into attribute without reflection. However, attribute doesn't work without reflection.
You should use AoP framework (castle, unity..etc).